# Plot wavelet coherence from sequences of numbers in R

Tags: r, time-series, wavelet, wavelet-transform, biwavelet

I have multiple sequences of numbers in a text file, each made up of numbers 1 to 8. Numbers within the sequence are separated by a space, while each new sequence comes with a newline.

Data: The text file 'Sequences.txt' can be assumed to have the following 4 sequences (different lengths possible):

6 6 3 8 3 2 8 6 1 7 3 7 6 8 2 8 2 6 8 8 1 1 4 3 6 4 3 4 6 7

6 1 8 7 8 1 2 6 8 3 4 3 5 4 2 2 1 1 1 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 7 7 4 4 3 2 8 7 7

4 5 5 7 7 3 7 8 7 8 2 2 8 2 8 1 1 1 7 7 7 4 4 4

1 4 4 1 1 8 8 1 8 1 1 1 1 5 5 6 6 7 3 3 8 2 3 4 3 8 3 4 5 4 5 2 3 5 7

What I need is a plot of the kind shown in the picture next using R. Here, each sequence is arranged in a row and the sequences are stacked one below the other.[image: File containing sequences]

From literature, it looks like a wavelet plot, though I'm not certain.

Can really use help with this task (have tried a few packages, including biwavelet, sowas). Not showing my attempt here since I've already posted that in another question. Using R 4.2.1.

Comment: It's not clear how you can expect to get such a plot with small runs of integers like this. Are you expecting the shorter vectors to be "stretched" to match the length of the longer vectors? Can you share a link to the actual "Sequences.txt" file?

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks, I understand what you mean. https://drive.google.com/file/d/172PCrf-qW7squTybDKnum74yR_v8npCX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AllanCameron I suppose length matching might indeed be required. I have been using the following colour scheme: colour_map <- c("red1", "yellow1", "red4", "orange", "lightblue", "green", "blue4", "violet") for unique numbers 1-8. For the extra padding, some different colour could be used.

Comment: I've had a play with this, and the end result is just noise with no discernable pattern whether you right-pad, left-pad or stretch the short vectors. What are the numbers supposed to represent?

Comment: @AllanCameron Numbers represent 8 clusters. I suppose I might be interested in right padding with the number '9' (since sequences are made with 1-8), and number 9 could be assigned 'white'. Hoping that the plot would show at least the colours which appear more often. Would you mind posting the code as answer to this question, or sharing that w/ me some other way? Thanks again.

Comment: OK - I have posted an answer. Not sure if that is what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be much of a pattern in the data, but you can extract and plot it as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

readLines("Sequences.txt") %>%
  strsplit(" ") %>%
  lapply(as.numeric) %>%
  lapply(\(x) c(x, rep(NA, max(lengths(.)) - length(x)))) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(seq_along(.)) %>%
  cbind(x = seq(nrow(.))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = "y", values_to = "z") %>%
  mutate(y = max(as.numeric(y)) - as.numeric(y) + 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", na.value = "white")
```

[image]

This image is essentially just showing you what the file looks like if you zoomed out and replaced each number with a color.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @AllanCameron. You have essentially replaced numbers w/ colours. This is not what I was looking for, but is certainly useful, and I've upvoted the answer. To make it more useful for others, adding some comments. 1. Custom colour palette can be introduced by replacing scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", na.value = "white") with scale_fill_gradientn(colors=c("orange", "red1", "blue4", "yellow1", "violet", "red4", "green", "lightblue"), na.value = "white"). 2. The heat plot can be made continuous by setting 'interpolate' argument to 'true' in geom_raster().